# Выборка по динамическим значениям двух столбцов, Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Есть таблица `table` со столбцами `date, time, number, ip`.

Необходимо по одному из значений `number` установить все записи с `date` и `ip`, а также указанным `number`, а затем выбрать из `table` иные `number`, совпадающие по каждой строке с полученных `date` и `ip` (не по совпадениям всего массива, а только по совпадению каждой динамической строки).

Вариант с выборкой `number` из всех возможных вариантов совпадения `date` и `ip` не устраивает, нужно только по каждой строке.

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить запрос.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, чего вы хотите. Пример бы помог. Подозреваю, что ответ в любом случае "group by" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял описание задачи, то ниже — решение.

в первом запросе выведены все поля и строки, во втором — только уникальные `number`, для которых есть совпадающие пары `(date,ip)` для заданного `number = 1`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00f8c/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (date int, number int, ip int);

insert into t values
  (1,1,1),
  (1,1,2),
  (2,1,1),
  (2,1,2),
  (1,2,1),
  (1,3,2),
  (2,4,1),
  (2,5,2),
  (1,6,3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
  from t t1, t t2
  where t1.number = 1
    and t1.number <> t2.number
    and t1.date = t2.date
    and t1.ip = t2.ip
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00f8c/1/0)**:

```
| date | number | ip | date | number | ip |
|------|--------|----|------|--------|----|
|    1 |      1 |  1 |    1 |      2 |  1 |
|    1 |      1 |  2 |    1 |      3 |  2 |
|    2 |      1 |  1 |    2 |      4 |  1 |
|    2 |      1 |  2 |    2 |      5 |  2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select distinct(t2.number)
  from t t1, t t2
  where t1.number = 1
    and t1.number <> t2.number
    and t1.date = t2.date
    and t1.ip = t2.ip
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00f8c/1/1)**:

```
| number |
|--------|
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      5 |
```

Comment: alexander barakin, спасибо Вам!  все заработало

Comment: если изложенное в ответе решение сработало, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: alexander barakin, можно ли как-то оптимизировать этот запрос? выбирает примерно 40 минут...

Comment: задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос. не забыв привести структуру таблицы, примерное число строк, используемые индексы, [план выполнения](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) запроса.