# Оптимизация таблицы и выборки mysql

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, select

Таблица:

```
Id int, date date, number int, ip varchar (int невозможно из-за точек)
Primary key - id, number.
```

Количество строк в таблице ~ 8.000.000.

Необходимо оптимизировать под запрос (подсказан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433320/178576)):

```
select t1.*, t2 from table t1, table t2
 where t1.number = значение
 and t1.number <> t2.number
 and t1.date = t2.date
 and t1.ip = t2.ip
```

explain:

```
ID| select_type| table| type| possible_keys|  key  | key_len|    ref|    rows|  Extra
 1|      SIMPLE|    t1|  ALL|        (null)| (null)|  (null)| (null)| 8029425|  Using where
 1|      SIMPLE|    t2|  ALL|        (null)| (null)|  (null)| (null)| 8029425|  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Помогите с решением

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) для вашего запроса.

Comment: ID| select_type| table| type| possible_keys| key| key_len| ref| rows| Extra|     1 SIMPLE t1 ALL (null) (null) (null) (null) 8029425 Using where    
1 SIMPLE t2 ALL (null) (null) (null) (null) 8029425 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

Comment: прошу прощения, забыл упомянуть: «в вопрос, а не в комментарий, потому что разбивки на строки в комментариях нет». нажав [edit]

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как показывает приложенный вывод `explain select ...`, при запросе вообще никаких ключей не используется: идёт прямой перебор всех строк. это долго. надо добавить индексы.

я бы предложил начать со столбца *number*.

и смотреть на вывод `explain select ...` после добавления каждого из индексов: ведь чем больше индексов закреплено за таблицей, тем дольше будет происходить *insert* (но, при хорошем наборе индексов, быстрее — *update* и *select*).

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь следует правильно расставить индексы.
Кроме того, ip хранить в числовом виде можно, и так делают: [пример из PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ip2long.php)

Comment: Индексы по отдельным полям без суррогатного ключа невозможно расставить, так как есть совпадающие строки. Поэтому сделал столбец ID с autoincrement. По нему и по столбцу number - primary_key

Comment: Что мешает повесить простые index на date и ip?

Comment: «ip хранить в числовом виде» — Потом будут проблемы с переездом на IPv6, да?

Comment: Если говорить о конкретной функции php, то да, она работает только с адресами ipv4.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
create index number_idx on table (number);
```

И добавить один (можно все, потом лишние удалить) из этих:

```
create index date_idx on table (date);
create index ip_idx on table (ip);
create index date_ip_idx on table (date, ip);
```

...в порядке тяжести. Без данных о количестве отфильтрованных записей по каждому из индексов сказать, какой из них будет лучше, сложно.